# Erro de múltiplos redirecionamento

Tags: c#

Antes não dava esse erro quando eu matava a sessão. O erro é esse: Como eu resolvo.

```
Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento
RecarregarOcultar detalhes
A página da web em http://localhost:2374/Default.aspx resultou em muitos redirecionamentos. Apagar seus cookies para este site ou permitir cookies de terceiros pode resolver o problema. Se não resolver, talvez o problema esteja na configuração do servidor, e não em seu computador.
Saiba mais sobre este problema.
Código de erro: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

A questão toda, não sei se é porque está no page load. Acabei de pegar um código com meu colega e ficou assim todo o meu Page Load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações   
            WFExecutor vcmpExecutor = null;

            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializações
                vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();

                //Desenvolvimento

                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (Request["hdfDsUsuarioRede"] != null)
                    {
                        //txtRecebeUsuario.Text = DecryptString(Request["hdfDsUsuarioRede"]);
                        txtRecebeUsuario.Text = (Request["hdfDsUsuarioRede"]);
                        Session["DsUsuarioRede"] = txtRecebeUsuario.Text;

                        VerificarSeguranca();
                    }

                    //if (Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString() == "2")
                    //{
                    //    Response.Redirect("/frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx");
                    //}

                    if (Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString() == "2")
                        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("/frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            Response.Redirect("/frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx");

                    if (Session["DsUsuarioRede"] != null)
                    {
                        VerificarSeguranca();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
```

E esse é o meu problema:

```
if (Session["DsTipoUsuario"].ToString() == "2")
                        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("/frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            Response.Redirect("/frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx");
                }
            }
```

Eu mato a sessão assim, passando um usuário para um HiddenField:

```
http://localhost:2374/?hdfdsusuariorede=scofva
```

É nesse momento que a coisa desanda.

Comment: Você tentou apagar os cookies?

Comment: Fiz uma edição e postei o meu problema

Comment: Esse código está em que classe? Da página Default ou da Mestre?

Comment: Está na página default